# Which Vimeo URLs can I include in a video sitemap that are not redirected or forbidden?

Tags: url, video-sitemap

I am not entirely sure what Vimeo URLs I can use for video sitemaps as they either seem to "redirect" or "forbidden" - both which would not really be acceptable in Google video XML sitemaps.

How do you create video sitemaps / which URLs do you use for Vimeo hosted videos?

Said in another way all my:

- http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=XXX ... redirects to underneath
- https://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=XXX ... gives not found
- https://player.vimeo.com/video/XXX ... gives forbidden